# Most Suitable Language/Framework to Create an Alarm Clock App?

Tags: android, alarm

I'm attempting to create a simple alarm clock app for Android that has these features:

1. Create/edit/delete alarms (obviously)
2. Only needs to store one alarm at a time
3. When alarm rings: turns on the screen (from sleep), displays alarm ringing screen, vibrates with a random pattern, & plays a short audio file on loop
4. Option to snooze or turn off alarm
5. Send commands to a web server hosted from a Raspberry Pi

So far I've been using React Native, but I've been encountering numerous issues with automatically turning on the screen and playing audio—more specifically with the modules not working correctly. After hours of debugging (to no avail), my assumption is that maybe React Native isn't the best framework with which to code this alarm app. If I am incorrect, please flame me. Thanks.

What is the most suitable language/framework with which to code this app?

Comment: Sorry, this was not a good question to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning to build only for Android then I would suggest you to go for Native development with Kotlin framework as it is widely used among developers nowadays. Community has started adapting to it long back and the response time to the queries are also quick to get your issues resolved soon.

Coming to the ReactNative framework, I started building my existing app into a new app using this framework and I felt good as I could use the same codebase for both the platforms Android & iOS until I had to scratch my head for getting things work in few cases. Like every other framework, this too has its own trade-off and we can't ignore that. I had to build few features using the native modules and this is how I ended by completing my project. For example, the push-notification package(https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) was used by the developers widely but it did't support(as of now) the latest In-line reply feature or it did't have the option of adding multiple actions to the Notification. This was one of the major requirement for my app and I had to implement using the native code rather than using this package. In some cases, you have to edit the native code locally from the package and use it.

To sum up, I would say that if you had already developed a project using ReactNative then try to check for packages which are needed as per your requirement. Use the most widely used packages. If not started then you can start with the native development.

For turning on the screen, you can try checking out this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wakeup-screen and see if this resolves your issue or atleast you will get some idea.